# Cannot full screen video in firefox while using Pipelight on hbonow

Tags: firefox-extensions, video-streaming, pipelight, drm

I recently subscribed to hbonow, which is unfortunately loaded with DRM that is very problematic to watch on linux. Fortunately I was able to get it working on Firefox using Pipelight by following these instructions:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274467

The only thing that is not working is full screen. When I click "full screen", the video moves to the upper left corner of the screen, but it is only large enough to fill roughly 1/3 of the entire screen. The rest of the screen is black. I tried lowering my display resolution from its native 1920x1080 to something smaller; then the video fills more of the screen area but is quite pixellated.

I have an Asus N56VM with integrated graphics and an Nvidia card, but the Nvidia card is disabled using the Prime configuration in nvidia-331.

I would like to try using it in Chrome, but apparently the lack of NPAPI plugin support in Chrome means that this will never work. I do realize this is a problem with hbonow, not a bug in Chrome or Pipelight, but does anyone have any ideas for workarounds that might fix it?

Comment: The lack of a flash Netscape plugin for chrome? It comes bundled with it.

Comment: Only the pipelight plugin can decode that kind of DRM video, not the bundled chrome plugin.