# HBONOW on Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: google-chrome, 16.04, video-streaming

I am trying to watch HBONow on Ubuntu 16.04LTS on Chrome browser. It is showing the certification video (i.e. PG-13, TV-MA) and then when it tries to load content it's never shows up.

My windows browser is able to load it successfully. What could be the possible solutions?

Comment: If I wait long enough after the hbo cert video mine says "Can't Play Video: We're having trouble playing this video. Please try again later". Is your error the same?

Comment: No I dont get the same error after waiting long

Comment: See possibly [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/633164/cannot-full-screen-video-in-firefox-while-using-pipelight-on-hbonow), [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274467), [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2273378), [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=194532), [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/watch-hbo-now-ubuntu/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/HBONow/comments/32lbrv/does_hbonow_run_on_linux/), [here](http://software.moftalk.com/hbo-now-and-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-64-bit-gnu-linux-60tLhnno.html). None of these have worked for me....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using Pipelight worked beautifully for me. It only runs in Firefox, though.

**Installing Pipelight**

Open up the old terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and copy and paste the following commands. To paste into the terminal do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
```

After adding the PPA, update the sources with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Next, you have to install Pipelight.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
```

Then, run the below command to update the plugin.

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

**Configuring Pipelight**

You may have to remove adobe-flashplugin, but I personally did not need to due to it not being installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove adobe-flashplugin
```

Then enable all of the necessary plugins

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable flash
```

Go one-by-one to ensure you're accepting each's license agreement

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable widevine
```

Finally:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

Then update Pipelight to recognize these plugins.

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

Finally, you must add the plugins to Firefox.

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```

**Testing it out!**

If done correctly, Pipelight should have installed an update version of Flash, Silverlight, and Widevine, which it runs through Wine, as can be seen in the Plugins section of the Add-ons Manager.

[image: Firefox plugins with up to date Flash, Silverlight and Widevine]

Finally, open up Firefox and test 'er out.

[image: HBO NOW on Ubuntu]

Source: https://www.maketecheasier.com/watch-hbo-now-ubuntu/

Comment: That didn't work for me : (

Comment: @costa Are you using Firefox? Did you get any errors along the way? Also open up the plugins in the Add-ons manager and post the plugins Firefox has installed. If a new version of Flash is not installed try restarting & repeating the whole process, making sure you say yes to the license agreements when you enable the plugins.

Comment: I didn't get any errors, as far as I can tell, but I don't see the plugins. Which means... I must have done something wrong : (

Comment: @Costa just try again making sure you agree to licenses during the enabling section

Comment: Woohoo! It works. I can't see what I did differently. Thanks so much!

Comment: There's some strange behavior with extra monitors and such, nothing I can't workaround, but I was wondering, if I wanted to reverse all this, would I simply need to `sudo apt-get remove pipelight` and `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:pipelight/stabe`?

Comment: @costa I believe you have to remove the plugins from Firefox too

Comment: When I do this, I am able to see video only when player is fullscreen. Once in fullscreen, none of the video player buttons are accessible, and I must use F-11 to back out. Does anyone else get this behavior?

Comment: @RghtHndSd I didn't experience that when I tested it back in June. I can't test it now though because the HBO Now free trial expired, sorry.

Comment: I think this answer has become obsolete as of Firefox v.52 (around March 2017), due to the termination of NPAPI plugin support https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/npapi-plugins?as=u&utm_source=inproduct :(

Comment: Didn't work for me. Probably because of the above comment :(

Answer (score 2):

Pipelight solution does not work at the moment, but Firefox with Flash on PlayOnLinux does.

1. Install and run PlayOnLinux

> ```
> sudo apt install playonlinux
>
> playonlinux
> ```

2. Click Install and search for Firefox

[image]

3. Select Flash when prompted
4. Run Firefox

[image]

5. Go to HBO website and if the videos still do not work, install the Flash they link to.

Comment: PlayOnLinux is a front-end for Wine. It permits to easily install Windows Games and software on Linux. I have apprehension installing anything related to Windows on  my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I am still clueless how to play videos from Hotstar on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to install the "hal" package (short for Hardware Abstraction Layer; it allows certain DRM-protected Flash content to verify what hardware device it's being played on, to prevent piracy)

Open a terminal (Alt-Ctrl-T) and add Martin Wimpress's HAL PPA (he's the developer behind Ubuntu MATE):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/hal-flash
```

Then update your package listing:

```
sudo apt update
```

and install hal:

```
sudo apt install libhal1-flash
```

Then, to make sure Flash is aware of the changes:

```
cd ~/.adobe/Flash_Player

rm -rf NativeCache AssetCache APSPrivateData2
```

Adobe does provide an online test to see if DRM in your player is working. The URL is http://drmtest2.adobe.com:8080/SVP/SampleVideoPlayer_FP.html , and you can test it by entering the following URL into the "video URL" box on that page: http://drmtest2.adobe.com:8080/Content/anonymous.f4v

Please let me know if this was helpful, or if you ran into any issues!

Comment: http://drmtest2.adobe.com:8080/Content/anonymous.f4v downloaded a file. Do not know what to do with this.

Comment: Please read my instructions again, slowly and carefully... If you go to the first URL, then "you can test it by entering the following URL into the 'video URL' box on that page", not by clicking the second URL directly.

Comment: didn't work on 17.04. :(