# Problem playing hotstar videos

Tags: google-chrome, video, streaming

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on my PC. I have a problem playing [Hotstar](http://www.hotstar.com/) videos on google chrome. Version of google chrome: 51.0.2704.63 (64-bit). All other videos of youtube are playing normally in google chrome. I even tried playing the [Hotstar](http://www.hotstar.com/) videos on Firefox but the same problem persists. Can anyone help me with the same ?

Comment: Just a black video window displaying loading circle.

Comment: I couldn't play hotstar videos on my linux mint too. But if you replace 'hotstar' with 'sudohotstar' in url, it will play the video in seperate host.

Comment: check this out easiest way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432437/2828219

Comment: @AkashPinnaka It used to be easiest way. Now it does not work. The website is not reachable.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. But you can use chrome extension to play hotstar video in hsplayer. Please check the link https://github.com/sweta20/hotstar-linux

Comment: Hotstar has started supporting linux. They moved their player to html5 few weeks back.

Answer (score 35):

Couple of solutions which worked for me - As of **Mar 20, 2017**

**Solution #1**. Play directly in Firefox/Google Chrome

1. In your browser, Open https://www.hlsplayer.net/ and select M3U8
   player (if not selected already)
2. Now we have to get the url to paste it in the input box.

   1. First, get id from video page. Say your video page is http://www.hotstar.com/sports/cricket/india-vs-australia-day-4/2001805383, id is 2001805383
   2. Open http://getcdn.hotstar.com/AVS/besc?action=GetCDN&asJson=Y&channel=TABLET&id=123&type=VOD . (Replace 123 with your actual video page id. Here it is 2001805383)
   3. In the json response, get the value of src. This is the url. **Ex**: It will be something [like](http://sshds8-lh.akamaihd.net/i/indvausdmw2017_ENGLISH_ENGDELINDVSAUST3D419032017_1@455565/master.m3u8?start=1489894474&hdnea=st=1489952406~exp=1489953006~acl=/*~hmac=b56ef452020939db177145dc9d4fe71c172e6c0c1c8ce36422493ae5641524c1).

I like this way because it allows you to go back in video/streaming.

**Note**: In case if it throws some error, repeat Step 2 and get url again (every time you do step2, you get a new url)

**Source**: Inspired by this solution [Quora](https://www.quora.com/I-am-not-able-to-see-videos-on-Live-Cricket-Scores-Live-Cricket-Streaming-on-starsports-com-on-Ubuntu-on-a-laptop-or-a-desktop-on-Firefox-or-Chrome-but-it-works-perfectly-on-Windows-7-Is-there-a-solution)

**Solution #2**. Play in Vlc

1. Install the dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php7.0 livestreamer
   ```
2. Clone/Download the project [here](https://github.com/biezom/hotstarsportslivestreamer)
3. Open terminal (bash), go to folder where its downloaded and run

   ```
   cd hotstarsportslivestreamer-master
   ./hotstarlivestreamer.sh
   ```

   (Follow the instructions provided by the script. Few tips: You can get hotstar link from browser. Write quality can be either "best" or "worst" according to your bandwidth)

*Advantage:* You can download the video as well

**Solution #3**. Play in Firefox

You can follow instructions here - [HBONOW on Ubuntu 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764727/hbonow-on-ubuntu-16-04lts/783717#783717)

*Advantage:* Once you do the step, videos will play seamlessly and effortlessly without performing any step for next videos.

*Disclaimer:* I haven't tried this solution personally though

So, upto you to pick one ;)

Comment: Solution 1 works!

Comment: #2 still works.  #1 - I got CDN url now from different means but still its not working

Comment: I have installed the dependencies mentioned at #2. Please elaborate how to "And run the script from

https://github.com/biezom/hotstarsportslivestreamer"?

Comment: @bluepearlsky added the instructions. Hope it helps

Comment: Is there a way to choose video quality in Solution 1? It works for me but I am only getting low quality video.

Comment: May be it depends on bandwidth. I get high quality video (my bandwidth is good)

Comment: easiest way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432437/2828219

Comment: Haha, read 1st line of the answer again ;)

Comment: I tried solution1 and it worked for me.

Comment: You don't have permission to access "http://getcdn.hotstar.com/AVS/besc?" on this server.

Answer (score 9):

I have the simplest and easiest solution.
Just install "User-Agent Switcher for Google Chrome" from Chrome web store.

[image]

**After Installing the extension Click on the extension...**

[image]

**Then Select the "Nexus 7 Tablet" option.**

Now you are good to go guys. Hotstar will buffer the videos but always check if the extension is turned on and selected as "Nexus 7 Tablet" option.

Comment: This is perhaps the only way to get it work on linux without too much of hassle as of December 2017

Comment: This doesn't work either - it shows "Launch App" as the option on the video player.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth trying to install HAL from Martin Wimpress's PPA. This stands for Hardware Abstraction Layer, and is required by some Flash content protected by DRM.

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/hal-flash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libhal1-flash
cd ~/.adobe/Flash_Player
rm -rf NativeCache AssetCache APSPrivateData2
```

Then restart your web browser and try playing Hotstar content again. This should work in Firefox; I'm not so sure about Chrome (since it comes with its own version of flash).

Comment: The above mentioned solution is not working.The problem still persists.

Comment: You could try the Pipelight instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/764727/hbonow-on-ubuntu-16-04lts/783717#783717 , though these instructions are for Firefox, not Google Chrome

Answer (score 3):

Method 1:

Step 1: Add HLS m3u8 chrome extension from chrome store and enable it. Link below:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-hls-m3u8/ckblfoghkjhaclegefojbgllenffajdc?hl=en
```

Step 2: Open Hotstar video link

```
http://www.hotstar.com/movies/escape-plan/1000074645/watch
```

Note: ID = 1000074645

Step 3: Open link below

```
http://getcdn.hotstar.com/AVS/besc?action=GetCDN&asJson=Y&channel=TABLET&id=123&type=VOD
```

Step 4: Replace url id=123 to id=ID as

```
http://getcdn.hotstar.com/AVS/besc?action=GetCDN&asJson=Y&channel=TABLET&id=1000074645&type=VOD
```

Output will be:

```
{"errorDescription":"200","message":"200","resultCode":"OK","resultObj":{"checkCacheResult":"","height":"360","src":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/movies/hindi/1000074645/1000074645_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?subtitle_identifier=1000074645&hdnea=st=1495051740~exp=1495052340~acl=/*~hmac=e9a791981ee7b95fa74d673db688d488f1416df5403165e3608987b3a12a19c0","width":"480"},"systemTime":1495052040}
```

Step 5: Take "src" out of it

src = `https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/movies/hindi/1000074645/1000074645_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?subtitle_identifier=1000074645&hdnea=st=1495051740~exp=1495052340~acl=/*~hmac=e9a791981ee7b95fa74d673db688d488f1416df5403165e3608987b3a12a19c0`

Step 6: Open it in new tab. It will work fine.

Method 2:

Step 1: Open below

```
http://demo.jwplayer.com/developer-tools/http-stream-tester/
```

Step 2: Open Hotstar video link

```
http://www.hotstar.com/movies/escape-plan/1000074645/watch
```

Note: ID = 1000074645

Step 3: Open link below

```
http://getcdn.hotstar.com/AVS/besc?action=GetCDN&asJson=Y&channel=TABLET&id=123&type=VOD
```

Step 4: Replace url id=123 to id=ID as

```
http://getcdn.hotstar.com/AVS/besc?action=GetCDN&asJson=Y&channel=TABLET&id=1000074645&type=VOD
```

Output will be:

```
{"errorDescription":"200","message":"200","resultCode":"OK","resultObj":{"checkCacheResult":"","height":"360","src":"https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/movies/hindi/1000074645/1000074645_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?subtitle_identifier=1000074645&hdnea=st=1495051740~exp=1495052340~acl=/*~hmac=e9a791981ee7b95fa74d673db688d488f1416df5403165e3608987b3a12a19c0","width":"480"},"systemTime":1495052040}
```

Step 5: Take "src" out of it

src = `https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/movies/hindi/1000074645/1000074645_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?subtitle_identifier=1000074645&hdnea=st=1495051740~exp=1495052340~acl=/*~hmac=e9a791981ee7b95fa74d673db688d488f1416df5403165e3608987b3a12a19c0`

Step 6: Put src in File url: adding place and hit Test Stream

Note: Open everthing in different tabs

It will work definately. In case of error repeat it.

[image]

Comment: This is working as of 17 September 2017.

Comment: Works as of Sep 28 2017.

Comment: Does not work for premium videos.

Comment: It's not a hack for premium videos. I will work only for free videos. @JyotmanSingh

Comment: doesn't work now I guess

Comment: @Suraj  If the 2nd method is not working. Use the 1st one I updated today.

Comment: Hotstar has updated their APIs and none of these will work now. I've forked an existing extension code and updated [here](https://github.com/vaikoovery/hotstar-linux)

Answer (score 2):

I was really thoughtful about being not working of hotstar, and then come to know below solution which can run hotstar videos easily on browser -

Step 1- Run http://www.hotstar.com/ on browser and reach your destination video.

Step 2- now then replace `hotstar` with `sudohotstar` in URL and press enter, your video will start running.

For example - you want to run below hotstar video
http://www.hotstar.com/sports/cricket/india-vs-australia-day-4/2001805383

put `sudo` in front of `hotstar` 
http://www.sudohotstar.com/sports/cricket/india-vs-australia-day-4/2001805383

Comment: I thought It was a dumb answer made up to gain some reputation but It works.

Comment: Not for making any reputation @SumeetDeshmukh, but to provide one spot solution.

Comment: Yeah i understand that but who purchased 'sudohotstar.com' just to mess with hotstar :)

Comment: Clearly doesn't work anymore. Site is unreachable

Answer (score 2):

The below solution worked for me.

1. Install and open **Google Chrome** (Chromium will not work as flash is required).
2. Go to Google Chrome webstore and install **hotstar linux** plugin.

   [image]
3. Restart Google Chrome.
4. Go to **www.hotstar.com** and play a video. It will not start playing.
5. Click on the **hotstar linux** icon on the top right corner.

   [image]

   A new tab opens and takes to **https://www.hlsplayer.net/**.
6. Click on **i** icon at the start of the url in the url bar. Allow flash for **https://www.hlsplayer.net/**.

   [image]

   If the video still does not start playing, close the tab and go back to **www.hotstar.com**. Again click on the top right icon for **hotstar linux**. It should start playing now.

Comment: Not working. I get `Error: Message: I/O error when loading media` while playing [Modern Family](http://www.hotstar.com/tv/modern-family/8549/its-the-great-pumpkin-phil-dunphy/1770004544).

Comment: It seems like it's a premium video. The way that this approach works, I don't think it will be useful for the premium videos. Sorry. Can you check if you're able to play the free ones? I will update my answer in that case with that information.

Comment: The plugin doesn't work for ipl matches. Just checked.

Answer (score 1):

- Open your hotstar page in Google Chrome.
- Press CTRL+SHIFT+I. Go to console tab.
- Double click CDN source. A m3u8 file will be downloaded.
- Open that m3u8 file with totem or vlc (Network setting should be
  right in vlc; totem use default Gnome Network setting)

  - Added benefits of this method is that you can edit m3u8 file in any text editor for reduced bandwidth if you have buffering issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just Re-Posting in 2019 that its best to use the user agent method to get it to work on Ubuntu. Default browser is Firefox for Ubuntu. I see an answer already in this page on using the user agent.

I’m on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, and use Mozilla Firefox Quantum 69.0 (64-bit).

Hooq content in hotstar do not load as they seem to see the user agent string of linux and don't load, you may get an error EXT_1 something like that, or something similar.

Apparently the hooq content on the hotstar servers need specific headers to be sent, and you will have to pretend to be a different device.

Use the Web developer tools in the browser and use responsive design mode to select Samsung Galaxy s9 and it starts playing, expand the screen as per need by dragging.

This will work most of the time.