# Hotstar videos on Ubuntu keeps freezing Google Chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

While it's great to see that Hotstar is finally officially supporting Ubuntu, I find that on my PC, even running a single tab of Hotstar constantly freezes Google Chrome. Is anyone else facing the same issue?

Comment: as an alternative you could try a few tricks from here ... https://askubuntu.com/questions/778906/problem-playing-hotstar-videos

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, hotstar.com does not support chrome on Linux ... the website opens however but the videos take forever to load(which is result of lack of support by hotstar for linux OS).

Where did you come across or hear about they supporting linux OS ?

You could install Windows version of firefox on wine if you are so particular to watch hotstar.com and you are an avid linux user just like me, that way hotstar.com is a go on linux

Comment: I can watch the hotstar videos playing in my Chrome browser on Linux. They load after about 30-40 seconds. What you are saying, used to happen earlier. But it's working now. The problem is just that it is consuming too much of computing if the tab is kept open for a long time.

Comment: oh ! ... I am surprised it isn't playing on my chrome linux its more than 4 mins now ... the way i remember its always been like this since i started with hotstar first.