# I can not play HBO videos in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in any of the browsers. How to fix this issue?

Tags: 16.04, video, flash, browser

I have tried everything, [HBONOW on Ubuntu 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764727/hbonow-on-ubuntu-16-04lts), I also tried the HAL lib and still it doesn't work in Chromium or Firefox browser. I also removed the Adobe Flash Plugin and tried using the pipelight and it still doesn't work. Can anybody help me with detailed steps to get that running?

These are all the steps I went through

1. Tried all the Pipelight installation steps:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove adobe-flashplugin
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
   sudo pipelight-plugin --update
   sudo pipelight-plugin --enable flash
   sudo pipelight-plugin --enable widevine
   sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
   sudo pipelight-plugin --update
   sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
   ```

   After doing all these steps, I tried restarting the browser and also the workstation. No luck.
2. Tried PlayOnLinux

   ```
   sudo apt install playonlinux
   playonlinux
   ```

   Installed the flash from here. But no luck.
3. I also tried running the alien and converted rpm files to Debian to install the Adobe Flash plugin PPAPI. No luck here as well.
   Downloaded the rpm file from Adobe place and converted it to deb package using the alien.
4. I also tried the Linux HAL lib

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/hal-flash
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install libhal1-flash
   cd ~/.adobe/Flash_Player
   rm -rf NativeCache AssetCache APSPrivateData2
   ```

   No luck here as well.
5. Removed all the flash plugin references and tried the manual file placement into the dpkg. It corrupted the filesystem and then I tried reinstalling UBUNTU from scratch.

All of them see to be successfull.
While chrome shows a message in the console -

```
{
    "message": "[Conviva] [1525029893.539] [ERROR] [SDK] [Config] load(): error loading configuration from local storage: undefined"
}
```

Firefox tends to ask a question saying do you want to run the flash player - It seems kind of awkward to me that even after I say, run - Nothing seems to work. There is no message in the console of the browser as well.

Here is an image what happens after installing the flash player:

[image]

Comment: I have been using the latest 16.04 latest LTS version.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @DavidFoerster Please check my update on the question

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *complete, verbatim* output of the listed commands? Did they (appear to) succeed? What *other symptoms* do you notice? What do the web browsers claim to know about available plug-ins? What *exactly* does "no luck" mean? How *exactly* did you determine that you were "unlucky"? What were the symptoms that led you to this belief? What other contextual information was there?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: As far as I can tell from what other people say on the internet it's impossible to get HBO videos to work in Firefox or Chromium since they dropped NPAPI support which disables all known work-arounds.

Answer (score 1):

Download Mozilla Firefox ESR 52.9.0(Windows 32 bit version) and install with PlayOnLinux, and Mozilla Firefox default profile, using "Use an installation file on my computer" option and selecting "Flash Player" during installation.